# I tried using for loop to make my code simpler but still getting errors

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am new to VBA and I recently wrote a code for UserForms. I had to write all 5 instances of a click event which are similar to each other but I can't figure out how to simplify them so I can just call on a private sub for each click event. Here is the code:

I am completely lost and any help in learning how to do this would be awesome. thanks!

```
  Private Sub chkAddleave1_Click()
    With SickLeaveForm
    If chkAddleave1 = True Then
    .txtShiftDate1.Enabled = True
    .txtShiftDate1.BackColor = &H80000005
    .OptionButtonAM1.Enabled = True
    .OptionButtonPM1.Enabled = True
    .OptionButtonND1.Enabled = True
    Else
    .txtShiftDate1.Enabled = False
    .txtShiftDate1.BackColor = &H8000000A
    .OptionButtonAM1.Enabled = False
    .OptionButtonPM1.Enabled = False
    .OptionButtonND1.Enabled = False
    End If
    End With
    End Sub
    
 Private Sub chkAddleave2_Click()
    With SickLeaveForm
    If chkAddleave2 = True Then
    .txtShiftDate2.Enabled = True
    .txtShiftDate2.BackColor = &H80000005
    .OptionButtonAM2.Enabled = True
    .OptionButtonPM2.Enabled = True
    .OptionButtonND2.Enabled = True
    Else
    .txtShiftDate2.Enabled = False
    .txtShiftDate2.BackColor = &H8000000A
    .OptionButtonAM2.Enabled = False
    .OptionButtonPM2.Enabled = False
    .OptionButtonND2.Enabled = False
    End If
    End With
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub chkAddleave3_Click()
    With SickLeaveForm
    If chkAddleave3 = True Then
    .txtShiftDate3.Enabled = True
    .txtShiftDate3.BackColor = &H80000005
    .OptionButtonAM3.Enabled = True
    .OptionButtonPM3.Enabled = True
    .OptionButtonND3.Enabled = True
    Else
    .txtShiftDate3.Enabled = False
    .txtShiftDate3.BackColor = &H8000000A
    .OptionButtonAM3.Enabled = False
    .OptionButtonPM3.Enabled = False
    .OptionButtonND3.Enabled = False
    End If
    End With
    End Sub
    Private Sub chkAddleave4_Click()
    With SickLeaveForm
    If chkAddleave4 = True Then
    .txtShiftDate4.Enabled = True
    .txtShiftDate4.BackColor = &H80000005
    .OptionButtonAM4.Enabled = True
    .OptionButtonPM4.Enabled = True
    .OptionButtonND4.Enabled = True
    Else
    .txtShiftDate4.Enabled = False
    .txtShiftDate4.BackColor = &H8000000A
    .OptionButtonAM4.Enabled = False
    .OptionButtonPM4.Enabled = False
    .OptionButtonND4.Enabled = False
    End If
    
    End With
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub chkAddleave5_Click()
    With SickLeaveForm
    If chkAddleave5 = True Then
    .txtShiftDate5.Enabled = True
    .txtShiftDate5.BackColor = &H80000005
    .OptionButtonAM5.Enabled = True
    .OptionButtonPM5.Enabled = True
    .OptionButtonND5.Enabled = True
    Else
    .txtShiftDate5.Enabled = False
    .txtShiftDate5.BackColor = &H8000000A
    .OptionButtonAM5.Enabled = False
    .OptionButtonPM5.Enabled = False
    .OptionButtonND5.Enabled = False
    End If
    End With
    
    End Sub
```

Here is what I have tried

```
    Private Sub EnableAddLeave()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim chkAddleave As MSForms.CheckBox
    Dim txtshiftdate As MSForms.textbox
    Dim OptionButtonAM As MSForms.OptionButton
    Dim OptionButtonPM As MSForms.OptionButton
    Dim OptionButtonND As MSForms.OptionButton
    
    For i = 1 To 5
    With SickLeaveForm
    If chkAddleave(i) = True Then
    txtshiftdate(i).Enabled = True
    txtshiftdate(i).BackColor = &H80000005
    OptionButtonAM(i).Enabled = True
    OptionButtonPM(i).Enabled = True
    OptionButtonND(i).Enabled = True
    Else
    txtshiftdate(i).Enabled = False
    txtshiftdate(i).BackColor = &H8000000A
    OptionButtonAM(i).Enabled = False
    OptionButtonPM(i).Enabled = False
    OptionButtonND(i).Enabled = False
    End If
    End With
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want each button to trigger autonomously or do you want to have everything checked now with one button?  (the way you have your code now with the for loop looks like you'll check all of them)

Comment: I wanted to trigger autonomously so not all can be checked as true when not needed.  both answers below were accurate as I have tested them both.

Comment: I thought you wanted to send which button clicked to the `EnableAddLeave` sub and from there change what's necessary like CDP did but without the loop but I guess it doesn't quite matter performance-wise to do it in such a small loop compared to what I meant.

Comment: That was an error on my part, I could have phrased my question more accurately.  What I meant was a click event for each check box and not one click to trigger all 5.  I needed them to activate only one at a time only when needed as it affects the outcome of the rest of the project i'm building.   I need to study more how the two answers arrived to the outcome I wanted tho so as not to just copy and past a code I do not completely understand. lol. but this is fun and I truly appreciate everyone's input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub EnableAddLeave()

    Dim i As Integer, bChk As Boolean
    With SickLeaveForm
        For i = 1 To 5
            bChk = .Controls("chkAddleave" & i)
           
            .Controls("OptionButtonAM" & i).Enabled = bChk
            .Controls("OptionButtonPM" & i).Enabled = bChk
            .Controls("OptionButtonND" & i).Enabled = bChk
            
            With .Controls("txtshiftdate" & i)
                .Enabled = bChk
                .BackColor = IIf(bChk, &HFFFFFF, &HC0C0C0)
            End With

        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh wow! You guys are legends! You answered that so fast. I have tried both answers and both are accurate to what I was intending on achieving. I shall study both answers and attempt to implement them on other situations like this. Thank you very much you have been very helpful. I wish i could mark both answers as correct as they both are

Comment: @CealizarSerrano you can parameterize the Sub and remove the loop eg `EnableAddLeave(i as integer)` so in `chkAddleave1_Click()` call with  ``EnableAddLeave(1)`

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the event handlers for each CheckBox but make them call your `EnableAddLeave` Sub and pass in references to the relevant controls on the UserForm ... no `For` loop required. For example (add this to the UserForm's code-behind):

```
Private Sub EnableAddLeave(chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox, txtBox As MSForms.TextBox, optBtnAm As MSForms.OptionButton, _
        optBtnPm As MSForms.OptionButton, optBtnNd As MSForms.OptionButton)
    If chkBox = True Then
        txtBox.Enabled = True
        txtBox.BackColor = &H80000005
        optBtnAm.Enabled = True
        optBtnPm.Enabled = True
        optBtnNd.Enabled = True
    Else
        txtBox.Enabled = False
        txtBox.BackColor = &H8000000A
        optBtnAm.Enabled = False
        optBtnPm.Enabled = False
        optBtnNd.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Then the event handler for each CheckBox can call this eg

```
Private Sub chkAddleave1_Click()
    EnableAddLeave chkAddleave1, txtShiftDate1, OptionButtonAM1, OptionButtonPM1, OptionButtonND1
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub chkAddleave2_Click()
    EnableAddLeave chkAddleave2, txtShiftDate2, OptionButtonAM2, OptionButtonPM2, OptionButtonND2
End Sub
```

And so-on for the other 3 CheckBoxes

Comment: Oh wow! You guys are legends! You answered that so fast. I have tried both answers and both are accurate to what I was intending on achieving. I shall study both answers and attempt to implement them on other situations like this.  Thank you very much you have been very helpful. I wish i could mark both answers as correct as they both are.